Trying to install MediaInfo Python 3.13 (Ubuntu) and it is not working out as expected
I am trying to install MediaInfo Python 3.13 (Ubuntu) and it is not working out as expected.
https://pymediainfo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
from pymediainfo import MediaInfo
media_info = MediaInfo.parse('/video.mp4')
for track in media_info.tracks:
    print(media_info)

Followed the instructions, OC Ubuntu.
When trying to execute the code, given commands. Returns an error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/user/data/www/c.py", line 11, in <module>
    media_info = MediaInfo.parse(file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/dist-packages/pymediainfo/__init__.py", line 434, in parse
    lib, handle, lib_version_str, lib_version = cls._get_library(library_file)
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/dist-packages/pymediainfo/__init__.py", line 329, in _get_library
    raise OSError(
    ...<3 lines>...
    )
OSError: Failed to load library from libmediainfo.so.0 - libmediainfo.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please tell me what I did wrong and how to solve it?

You installed the MediaInfo library Python wrapper without having installed MediaInfo library, so:
sudo apt install libmediainfo0

